# Firestore rule for updating if not in array

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am updating an array with values

```
recipe.update({
    ingredient_list: arrayUnion('tomato')
    ingredients_number: increment(1)
})
```

I need a rule to only allow incrementing `ingredients_number` if `tomato` was not already in the array.
I tried extracting the value of arrayUnion like so and checking if it is in the array:

```
match recipes/{recipe} {
  allow update: if request.resource.data.ingredient_list[0] in resource.data.ingredient_list;
}
```

Problem 1: Extracting value within `arrayUnion`
Problem 2: Negating `in` operator.

Other approaches welcome.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in brackets and use "!" `!(value in array)`